# MUI Grid Layout - 2 different layout in Mobile and browser view

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, grid, grid-layout

I am working on a layout design which will have **browser view** (aka `lg`) and **mobile view** (aka `xs`). And is there anyway to design the follow layout since I have spend a day but still struggle in build the layout.

**Live Code is here**, I can create the layout separately, but struggle to merge it to one : [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/layout-6wndrt?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt461aea0006356k92kiiumg%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt461aea0002356kpoqs42hw%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt461aea0003356kh74dulks%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt461aea0005356kr35joaa1%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B40%252C60%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clt461aea0002356kpoqs42hw%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt461aea0002356kpoqs42hw%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%257D%252C%2522clt461aea0005356kr35joaa1%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt461aea0005356kr35joaa1%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clt465nsk00di356kl0hn9qup%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt465nsk00di356kl0hn9qup%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clt461aea0003356kh74dulks%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt461aea0003356kh74dulks%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

1. is there way to create the following layout?
2. if not, can I add a `if` statement to render two layout?

Browser Layout:
[image: Browser Layout]

Mobile Layout:
[image: Browser Layout]